# convert from httppostedfile to htmlinputfile

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

how do I convert an httppostedfile to an htmlinputfile? I'm working with an old mess of an app and so far have been able to refactor it so it makes a bit of sense, but this particular mess is too tangled to be worth the effort :S.

Thanks, as usual, for the help

relevant code:

collection:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Public Class ArchivosCollection
    Inherits CollectionBase

    Default Public Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As HtmlInputFile
        Get
            Return MyBase.List(index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As HtmlInputFile)
            MyBase.List(index) = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Add(ByVal oArchivo As HtmlInputFile) As Integer
        Return MyBase.List.Add(oArchivo)
    End Function

    Public Function getDataSource() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim oArchivo As HtmlInputFile
        Dim fila As DataRow
        Dim orden As Integer = 0
        dt.Columns.Add("documento", GetType(System.String))
        dt.Columns.Add("tipo", GetType(System.String))
        For Each oArchivo In list
            If Not oArchivo.Disabled Then
                fila = dt.NewRow()
                fila("documento") = Trim(Path.GetFileName(oArchivo.PostedFile.FileName))
                fila("tipo") = Trim(oArchivo.PostedFile.ContentType)
                dt.Rows.Add(fila)
            End If
        Next
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Function ExisteArchivo(ByVal Nombre As String) As Boolean
        For Each oArchivo As HtmlInputFile In list
            If Not oArchivo.Disabled Then
                If Path.GetFileName(oArchivo.PostedFile.FileName) = Nombre Then
                    Return True
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function

    Public Function EliminarArchivo(ByVal Nombre As String) As Boolean
        For Each oArchivo As HtmlInputFile In list
            If Not oArchivo.Disabled Then
                If Path.GetFileName(oArchivo.PostedFile.FileName) = Nombre Then
                    oArchivo.Disabled = True
                    Return True
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

old code:

```
Private Sub btnAgregarDocumento_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAgregarDocumento.Click
    Try
        If Not (Me.fleDocumento.PostedFile Is Nothing) Then
            If Trim(Me.fleDocumento.PostedFile.FileName) = "" Then
                Throw New Exception(rm.GetString("errorDebeEscogerUnArchivo"))
            End If
            If Not Servicios.isValidUploadType(Me.fleDocumento.PostedFile.FileName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Filtros Upload")) Then
                Throw New Exception(rm.GetString("errorExtensionNovalida"))
            End If
            Dim oArchivosOT As ArchivosCollection
            If Session("oArchivosOT") Is Nothing Then
                oArchivosOT = New ArchivosCollection
            Else
                oArchivosOT = Session("oArchivosOT")
            End If
            If oArchivosOT.ExisteArchivo(Path.GetFileName(Me.fleDocumento.PostedFile.FileName)) Then
                Throw New Exception(rm.GetString("errorArchivoYaExiste"))
            End If
            oArchivosOT.Add(Me.fleDocumento)
            Me.dgDocumentos.DataSource = oArchivosOT.getDataSource()
            Me.dgDocumentos.DataBind()
            Session("oArchivosOT") = oArchivosOT
            If Request.QueryString("desde") = "proy" Then
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "msg", "<script>window.opener.document.Form1.refGridDocs.click();</script>")
            End If
        Else
            Throw New Exception(rm.GetString("errorDebeEscogerUnArchivo"))
        End If
    Catch exc As Exception
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "msg", Servicios.MsgBox(exc.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```

new code (partial):

```
Dim archivos As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
            Dim colArchivos As ArchivosCollection = IIf(Session("oArchivosOT") Is Nothing, New ArchivosCollection(), Session("oArchivosOT"))
            Dim i
            For i = 0 To archivos.Count
                colArchivos.Add(DirectCast(archivos(i), HtmlInputFile))
            Next

            Session("oArchivosOT") = colArchivos
```

Comment: The question does not make sense to me - `HtmlInputFile` is a control. `HttpPostedFile` gives access to files uploaded with it. You can't convert between the two. Posting the code you are having problems with would be more useful, as well as explaining exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: we're trying to implement multi-file upload in some of our pages. right now files are uploaded using a custom htmlinputfile collection that is stored in a session variable so it can be mangled and raped by 100 or so pages before finally being accessed by a function that stores the files inside it and does 20 other things in its 1000 lines of code. since this collection has htmlinputfile as its type and I need to do this by tomorrow morning I guessed the best way would be to cast it to htmlinputfile. I'll post the relevant code in my question.

Comment: Please also add the relevant information from your comment (!?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`PostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputfile.postedfile.aspx) property of the `HtmlInputFile` object is a `HttpPostedFile` object - you can simply access it for each `HtmlInputFile`.

Comment: after looking at your comment I thought as much.

Thanks! =)

Comment: this property is read only. is there any way to create an htmlinputfile from an httppostedfile?

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso - Not that I am aware of.